# Adding multiple images in excel using PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

**This issue is solved with workaround.** If I copy multiple images, using PhpSpreadsheet in excel, having same image name and different paths, than only last image is added multiple times. But if I rename images with different names, than it's working fine. Eg, if I copy `path1/thumb.png` and `path2/thumb.png` to excel, than `path2/thumb.png` will be copied two times. But if if I copy, `path1/image1.png and path2/image2.png`, than it's working fine. Example

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$name = "image.xlsx";    
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($name);
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);

$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
//$drawing->setPath("path1/thumb.png");  I AM COPING AND UPDATING NAME
copy("path1/thumb1.png","thumb1.png");//WORKAROUND FOR THIS ISSUE
$drawing->setPath("thumb1.png");
$drawing->setName('Logo');
$drawing->setCoordinates('B2');
$drawing->setWidthAndHeight(500, 500);
$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0));   
$writer->save( $name );

$writer2 = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer2->save($name);
$writer2 = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$drawing1 = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
//$drawing->setPath("path2/thumb.png"); THIS WILL OVERWRITE ABOVE path1/thumb1.png, and will be inserted twice.
copy("path2/thumb1.png","thumb2.png");//WORKAROUND FOR THIS ISSUE
$drawing1->setPath("thumb2.png");
$drawing->setName('New image');
$drawing1->setCoordinates('B24');
$drawing1->setWidthAndHeight(500, 500);
$drawing1->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0));  
$writer2->save( $name );
?>
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You overwrite with

> `$writer2 = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);`

the first image.

Try

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$name = "image.xlsx";    
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($name);
$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);

$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$drawing->setPath("thumb1.png");
$drawing->setName('Logo');
$drawing->setCoordinates('B2');
$drawing->setWidthAndHeight(500, 500);
$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0));   

$drawing1 = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$drawing1->setPath("thumb2.png");
$drawing1->setName('New image');
$drawing1->setCoordinates('B24');
$drawing1->setWidthAndHeight(500, 500);
$drawing1->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0));  
$writer->save( $name );
?>
```

Comment: I have tried your code and found no difference. Exactly same result.